# MongoMapper in a custom gem with rspec

Tags: ruby, rspec, mongomapper

Hopefully I'm just missing something simple. I am using mongomapper in a rails 3 app and it works beautifully. I needed to share it with another app and pushed it out to a gem, which also works great from both rails apps. However, when I try to add rspec tests to the gem I am getting the following error:

/Users/dane/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rspec-core-2.5.2/lib/rspec/core/backward_compatibility.rb:20:in `const_missing': uninitialized constant User::MongoMapper (NameError)

I am adding a really simple test for my User model.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you require 'mongo_mapper' in the spec/spec_helper?  The error indicates that MongoMapper is not defined in the top level namespace, so you probably forgot to do that.